# Loading inline jQuery scripts along with deferred and async scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, optimization, lazy-loading

I am working on a website and working on its Page Speed Insights and have a

```
Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
```

So basically what happen is I have two external javascript import  on top of the page which is:

```
<script src="/remotestaff_2015/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/remotestaff_2015/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This website has lot of javascripts but some are at the bottom of the page after the `<body>` tag. So my problem is those two on the top. To fix the render block I already searched on google and found out that I can use the `defer` or `async` attribute. My problem is that there are some modules on the website that has inline javascripts like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");

    if ($("#wrapper").hasClass("toggled")) {

        $(".color-fade").css("opacity", ".5");

    } else {

        $(".color-fade").css("opacity", "1");

    }

});
```

So if I put defer on my  `jquery` file I'll have an error on my inline javascripts because it will load without the jquery loaded yet. Is there a way to fix this inline scripts or somehow make them run after the deferred jquery or other js files has been loaded? I don't want to put those inline scripts in other file.

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN:

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script
>   is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before
>   firing **DOMContentLoaded**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Therefore let your inline script wait for the document and the deferred scripts to be loaded. The `DOMContentLoaded` event will fire when that has happened:

```
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
          // Inline scripts go here
        });
    </script>
```

Notice that the `$(document).ready(function()` is not required any more, because that would wait for the same event (`DOMContentLoaded`).

Answer (score 0):

you can load your js dynamically in

`$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});`

for dynamically loading scripts you ca use code

```
var script = document.createElement("script")
script.type = "text/javascript";

if (script.readyState){  //IE
    script.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                script.readyState == "complete"){
            script.onreadystatechange = null;
            callback();
        }
    };
} else {  //Others
    script.onload = function(){
        callback();
    };
}

script.src = url;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Please let me know if it helped you.

Answer (score -1):

I would do this to make everything clean. Load jQuery file without defer and define menu toggling event in HTML head.

```
<script src="/remotestaff_2015/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // option 1
        /* $('#menu-toggle').click(function() {
            // your code
        }); */
    });

    // option 2
    $(document).on('click', '#menu-toggle', function() {
        // your code
    });
</script>
```

Now you can render the element anywhere in HTML body or even from AJAX callback.

Comment: Actually I want to do this and this is the cleanest way but just as I've said I can't do that because there are a lot of scripts in this site and I may break things if I move the jquery somewhere like in the bottom. I needed to defer jquery so that it's ok to remain it on top but problem is the inline scripts. There are a lot of scripts which is depended on jquery so I will defer jquery so does the others including inline scripts without moving its position.

Comment: Do you mean you can only load the jQuery file in runtime, while the other scripts (which use jQuery) are loaded earlier?

Comment: No, I want to defer loading jquery then load inline scripts after jquery has been loaded.

Comment: Change all your inline scripts from `.click()` to `$(document).on('click', <selector>, function() { })` and don't defer the jQuery.